# How to send raw 802.11 packets (e.g. mgmt, control) via kernel drivers (e.g. NDIS filter) on Windows?

Tags: windows, driver, ndis, wifi

I have a [NDIS 6 filter driver](https://github.com/nmap/npcap) working on Windows Vista and later systems. I have successfully captured raw 802.11 packets like what I said in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36566978/how-to-determine-whether-a-802-11-raw-packet-has-fcs-4bytes-in-a-ndis-6-filter). You can find more info about raw 802.11 packets [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/network/indicating-raw-802-11-packets).

The question that I faced now is that `is it also possible to send raw 802.11 packets on Windows via a kernel driver?` I didn't find any explanation on MSDN that said clearly it's possible or not.

At present, the driver can send Ethernet packets. What should I modify in the driver to support sending raw 802.11 packets? (or won't need change anything, just send the raw 802.11 packet bytes like how I send as Ethernet data?)